# How to show group inside the circular graph in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

**the sample data setup**

```
brand=c('MS', 'Google', 'Apple', 'MS', 'FB', 'Apple', 'Oracle')
product=c('OS', 'Search', 'Iphone', 'Search', 'Network', 'OS', 'DB')
noOfProduct = c(10,23,84,120,38,1,90)
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
brandData <- data.frame(id, brand,product, noOfProduct)
```

**how the data look like**

```
  id  brand product noOfProduct
1  1     MS      OS          10
2  2 Google  Search          23
3  3  Apple  Iphone          84
4  4     MS  Search         127
5  5     FB Network          38
6  6  Apple      OS           1
7  7 Oracle      DB         900
```

Now I want to display in a circular histogram, here the code of the graph

```
library(ggplot2)

label_data=brandData
number_of_bar=nrow(label_data)
angle= 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

ggplot(brandData, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=noOfProduct, fill=brand)) +       
    geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
    ylim(-100,200) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
    )  +
    coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=noOfProduct, label=product, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE )
```

the output graph looks like [image]

Now I want to show the brand name inside the circle and with each bar so it will be easily understandable and self explanatory, can someone please help me in this regard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this by changing your `y` to be `0` and modifying your `hjust`:

If you replace your `geom_text` code with the below you should get:

```
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=0, label=product, hjust=ifelse(hjust==1, -0.1, 1.1)), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, 
            inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Mike, I am able to achieve this by adding below mentioned code below my code -- geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=0, label=brand, hjust=ifelse(hjust==1, -0.1, 1.1)), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE)